# How to send data from a device to IOT HUB?

Tags: android, azure-iot-hub

I am new to Cloud Technology and I want to send the data from Android Device to IoT Hub using Android Studio, I am able to send data using device to IoT Hub by referring to the https://learn.microsoft.com i.e; "Send device-to-cloud messages to IoT Hub"

I am able to get the device ID of a particular device from Android Studio and I want it to be displayed in IoT Hub using Android Studio,

Kindly help me or refer some site for specific Android Device to IOT Hub Connectivity and Data transfer

Answer (score 1):

On Android Device,there are two solutions to implement IoT Hub Connectivity and Data transfer.

1. Directly sending data to IoT Hub(device-to-cloud) and receiving data from IoT Hub(cloud-to-device).You can use [Azure IoT Hub for Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java), the Device SDK can be used on Android with the API version 17 and higher. And please refer to [Connect your device to your IoT hub using Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted),in this guide,tutorial shows you how to creates a device identity and associated security key to connect your device app.
2. Make [Node.JS apps for Android](https://github.com/node-on-mobile/node-on-android) with [Azure IoT device SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/tree/master/device).Please note that this way only supports ARM64 Currently.

Either way can implement your needs as long as you like.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion I will try both.