# How to Send Events from Linux Machine to Azure IoT Edge Hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have successfully deployed my first IoT Edge Device to Azure IoT Hub. The edge device is Ubuntu 16.04 I used the following link as a guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart-linux

The link uses tempSensor to generator realtime streaming data.

On my Ubuntu I have installed a realtime event stream generator of json using the following link http://acesinc.net/introducing-a-streaming-json-data-generator/

When I check the logs see events on my Ubuntu machine I can see the logs from the tempSensor but I can't see the events from my streaming event generator.

The problem is I can see the logs (traffic being generatored) from the tempSensor, however I can't see the traffic being generated from my realtime traffic.

I did some research and I discovered that in order to send events to the edge hub I would need to create a custom module that receives a message and send it to the Edge Hub. I therefore would need to modify the streaming generator to a module SDK to send the data. It was suggested that I follow the guide at the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-csharp-module

Now, the problem is the guide from link is based on simulated IoT edge device that uses data generator based on the tempSensor. Whereas my Ubuntu uses totally different generator. So I attempted to only as much from the guide that I think would enable to me get my Ubuntu to send events to the IoT Edge hub.

My configuration is as follows:

> namespace mycsharpmodule4 {
>       using System.Collections.Generic;     // for KeyValuePair<>
>       using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared; // for TwinCollection
>       using Newtonsoft.Json;                // for JsonConvert
>       using System;
>       using System.IO;
>       using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
>       using System.Runtime.Loader;
>       using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
>       using System.Text;
>       using System.Threading;
>       using System.Threading.Tasks;
>       using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;
>       using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.Mqtt;
>
> ```
>  class MessageBody {   
> public Machine machine {get;set;}
> public Ambient ambient {get; set;}
> public string timeCreated {get; set;} } class Machine {    public double temperature {get; set;}
>         } class Ambient {    public double temperature {get; set;}    public int humidity {get; set;}          }
>
> }
> ```

Just so you know, I have followed everything in guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-csharp-module

When I try build the code by running the command, 'Build IoT Edge Solution' I get the following error:

**CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [C:\app\mycsharpmodule4.csproj]
The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet publish -c Release -o out' returned a non-zero code: 1**

See image for complete view of error in Visual Studio Code.

[visualstudiocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pyVz.png)

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong.

I'm checked on Stack Exchange for similar questions and came across

[How to send data from a device to IOT HUB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810999/how-to-send-data-from-a-device-to-iot-hub) . However, I was unable to make it work for me.

I have been at this for nearly 7 days now, and I'm about to give up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Paul

Comment: I was having a lot issues trying to format the code properly - truly sorry about that.

Comment: Have you checked the Main method had not been deleted in the Progam.cs?It seems that the project need a static method called main, with the correct signature. That's how the compiler knows how to start your program. Could you please provide all the code in Progam.cs?

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT, thanks for reaching out. I have come to the conclusion that I need to study more on programming code in C#. I don't even understand what Main method is, so I need to first appreciate the fundamentals. I will reopen this question when I can understand what I'm doing. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free let me if there is any question.